# How to read Number from Parse and change photo, using objective-c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, parse-platform

We've read plenty of numbers into parse.com from moisture sensor,
it is a series data of "Number" type, from 400-800,
What we going to do is,
when the number < 600, we change the photo in our xcode storyboard to "good",
when it is >600, we change it to "need water".
We're using objective-c.

I'm stuck in the codes to read the data into the app and
need your help.

Comment: Please post the part of your code you are having trouble with

Answer (score 0):

With the amount of code (none) you provide, it is practically impossible to answer your question correctly. Please provide concrete code and tell us what you mean with "good" and "need water".

Basically, let's say you have an NSNumber from 400 to 800 and have it in a

```
PFObject *object
```

which has some kind of "number" key:

```
NSNumber *number = [object objectForKey:@"number"];
if ([number intValue] <= 600) {
 //do whatever you want to do with GOOD photos
}
else {
 //do whatever you want to do with BAD photos
}
```

Again, please provide more information so that we can help you!